# KeyPress is not calling in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am capturing an event on enter through a selector. but it is not capturing.

```
var trID;
row.click(function() {
        var tr = $(watchRow).find('tr');            
        $('tr').not(this).removeClass('highlight');
        $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
        trID = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(trID);                        
    });

row.find('trID').keypress(
            function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    //selfReference.addSymbolToWatch();
                    alert("You Press Enter!");
                }
    });
```

i am getting trID but actually what i want to do is when the row is selected then it is able to trigger an enter event on pressing enter.

Comment: What is the `row` variable in your code?  Where is it defined?

Comment: row contains the html which is dynamic populating the records.

Comment: I think we'd need to be able to see both your HTML and the code that defines the `row` variable because `row.find('trID')` is looking for `<trID>` tags in whatever the row jQuery object is which seems pretty unusual.  Is that really want you want to be looking for?

Comment: whatif i do row.find(trId) then i think it could find a row with a specific id

Comment: jfriend, what i want to do actually is. i want to call keypress enter on a selected row. row is a html which is having a <tr>.

Comment: Show us the HTML and tell us what you're trying to find and we can help you.  Without the HTML, we're just making wild guesses.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make the tr focusable by adding the attribute `focusable` to be able to capture keypresses.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it works as you requested when the 'TR' is selected

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('tr').live('keypress',function(){
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {     
                    alert("You Press Enter!");   
                } 
            });
        });
```